# How to retrieve a random word of a given length from a Trie

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, tree, trie

I have a simple Trie that I'm using to store about 80k words of length 2 - 15.  It works great for checking to see if a string is a word; However, now I need a way of getting a random word of a given length.  In other words, I need "getRandomWord(5)" to return a 5 letter word, with all 5 letter words having an equal chance of being returned.

The only way I can think of is to pick a random number and traverse the tree breadth-first until I've passed that many words of the desired length.  Is there a better way to do this?

Possibly unnecessary, but here's the code for my trie.

```
class TrieNode {
    private TrieNode[] c;
    private Boolean end = false;

    public TrieNode() {
        c = new TrieNode[26]; 
    }

    protected void insert(String word) {
        int n = word.charAt(0) - 'A';
        if (c[n] == null)
            c[n] = new TrieNode();
        if (word.length() > 1) {
            c[n].insert(word.substring(1));
        } else {
            c[n].end = true;
        }
    }

    public Boolean isThisAWord(String word) {
        if (word.length() == 0)
            return false;
        int n = word.charAt(0) - 'A';
        if (c[n] != null && word.length() > 1)
            return c[n].isThisAWord(word.substring(1));
        else if (c[n] != null && c[n].end && word.length() == 1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Edit: The marked answer worked well; I'll add my implementation here for posterity, in case it helps anyone with a similar problem.

First, I made a helper class to hold metadata about the TrieNodes I'm using in the search:

```
class TrieBranch {
    TrieNode node;
    int letter;
    int depth;
    public TrieBranch(TrieNode n, int l, int d) {
        letter = l; node = n; depth = d;
    }
}
```

This is the class that holds the Trie and implements the search for the random word.  I'm kind of a beginner so there may be better ways to do this, but I tested this a bit and it seems to work.  No error handling, so caveat emptor.

```
class Dict {

    final static int maxWordLength = 13;    
    final static int lettersInAlphabet = 26;
    TrieNode trie;
    int lengthFrequencyByLetter[][];
    int totalLengthFrequency[];

    public Dict() {
        trie = new TrieNode();
        lengthFrequencyByLetter = new int[lettersInAlphabet][maxWordLength + 1];
        totalLengthFrequency = new int[maxWordLength + 1];
    }

    public String getRandomWord(int length) {
        // Returns a random word of the specified length from the trie
        // First, pick a random number from 0 to [number of words with this length]
        Random r = new Random();
        int wordIndex = r.nextInt(totalLengthFrequency[length]);

        // figure out what the first letter of this word would be
        int firstLetter = -1, totalSoFar = 0;
        while (totalSoFar <= wordIndex) {
            firstLetter++;
            totalSoFar += lengthFrequencyByLetter[firstLetter][length];
        }
        wordIndex -= (totalSoFar - lengthFrequencyByLetter[firstLetter][length]);

        // traverse the (firstLetter)'th node of trie depth-first to find the word (wordIndex)'th word
        int[] result = new int[length + 1];
        Stack<TrieBranch> stack = new Stack<TrieBranch>();
        stack.push(new TrieBranch(trie.getBranch(firstLetter), firstLetter, 1));
        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            TrieBranch n = stack.pop();
            result[n.depth] = n.letter;

            // examine the current node
            if (n.depth == length && n.node.isEnd()) {
                wordIndex--;
                if (wordIndex < 0) {
                    // search is over
                    String sResult = "";
                    for (int i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
                        sResult += (char)(result[i] + 'a');
                    }
                    return sResult;
                }
            }

            // handle child nodes unless they're deeper than target length
            if (n.depth < length) {
                for (int i = 25; i >= 0; i--) {
                    if (n.node.getBranch(i) != null)
                        stack.push(new TrieBranch(n.node.getBranch(i), i, n.depth + 1));
                }
            }
        }
        return "failure of some sort";
    }
}
```

Using a casual dictionary (80k words max length 12) each call to getRandomWord() takes abount .2ms, and using a more thorough dictionary (250K words, max length 24) each call takes about 1ms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make sure you have an even chance of getting each 5-letter word, you need to know how many 5-letter words there are in your tree.  So as you construct the tree, you add the length of the word you're adding to two counters: an overall frequency counter, and a by-letter frequency counter:

```
int lengthFrequencyByLetter[letterIndex][maxWordLength-1]
int totalLengthFrequency[maxWordLength-1]
```

So if you have 4000 5-letter words, and 213 of them start with "d", then

```
lengthFrequencyByLetter[3][4] = 213
```

and

```
totalLengthFrequency[4] = 4000
```

after you're done adding everything to your tree.  (The letter "a" is 0, "b" is 1, ... "z" is 25.)

From here, you can do a search for the `n`th word of a given `length`, where `n` is a random integer picked from a uniform random distribution, in the range (0, `totalLengthFrequency[length-1]`).

Let's say you have 4000 5-letter words in your structure.  You pick random number 1234.  Now you can check

```
lengthFrequencyByLetter[0][4]
lengthFrequencyByLetter[1][4]
lengthFrequencyByLetter[2][4]
lengthFrequencyByLetter[3][4]
```

in turn, until you exceed a total of 1234.  Then you know quickly what the start letter of the 1234th 5-letter word is, and then search there.  You don't have to search every word in the tree from the beginning each time.

Comment: Thanks, I feel dumb now!  I haven't tried it out yet but this makes sense and I'm pretty sure it will serve my purposes.