# How to get random words of a give length (L) from a dictionary which has been implemented using a trie?

Tags: data-structures, trie

[How to retrieve a random word of a given length from a Trie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17152269/how-to-retrieve-a-random-word-of-a-given-length-from-a-trie)

The answer above explains how to select the first character but I am confused how we will proceed after that. I want words of Length L but when I start traversing the tree, I wouldn't know if the branch that is being traversed has depth L.

**Dictionary**

```
package com.FastDictionary;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import sun.rmi.runtime.Log;

/**
 * Dictionary implementation.
 * Uses Trie Data Structure
 * Creates a singleton object
 */
public class FastDictionary {

    private int nineWordCount;
    private int totalWordCount;

    // Root Node
    private DictionaryNode root;

    // Singleton object
    private static FastDictionary fastDictionary;

    // Flag; True if words.txt has been processed once
    private boolean isProcessed;

    private FastDictionary() {

        this.root = new DictionaryNode();
        isProcessed = false;
        this.nineWordCount = 0;
        this.totalWordCount = 0;
    }

    private boolean sanitiseSearch(String text) {

        if (text == null) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return text.matches("[a-zA-Z]");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add a word to Dictionary
     * @param word word to be added
     */
    public void addWord(String word) {

        if (word == null) {

            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Word to be added to Dictionary can't be null");
        }

        // Sanitise input
        if (word.contains(" ")) {

            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Word to be added to Dictionary can't contain white spaces");
        }

        DictionaryNode currentNode = this.root;

        for (char c: word.toCharArray()) {

            DictionaryNode child = currentNode.getChild(c);

            if (child == null) {

                currentNode = currentNode.addChild(c);
            }
            else {

                currentNode = child;
            }
        }
        // Last node contains last character of valid word
        // Set that node as Leaf Node for valid word
        currentNode.setLeaf();
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param word String to be checked if it is a valid word
     * @return True if valid word
     */
    public boolean isWord(String word) {

        if (word == null) {

            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Word to be added to Dictionary can't be null");
        }

        // Sanitise input
        if (word.contains(" ")) {

            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Word to be added to Dictionary can't contain white spaces");
        }

        DictionaryNode currentNode = this.root;
        for (char c: word.toCharArray()) {

            DictionaryNode child = currentNode.getChild(c);

            if (child == null) {

                return false;
            }
            currentNode = child;
        }

        // Returns true if Last Character was leaf
        return currentNode.isLeaf();
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param text String that needs to be searched
     * @return List of Strings which are valid words searched using 'text'
     *
     */
    public ArrayList<String> getWords(String text) {

        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        DictionaryNode currentNode = this.root;

        for (int i = 0; i < text.length() ; i++) {

            DictionaryNode child = currentNode.getChild(text.charAt(i));

            if (child == null) {

                return words;
            }

            if (child.isLeaf()) {
                words.add(text.substring(0,i+1));
            }

            currentNode = child;

        }
        return words;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param inputFileStream Text file containing list of valid words
     * Switches Flag isProcessed to True
     */
    public void processFile(InputStream inputFileStream) {

        try {

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputFileStream));
            String line;

            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                line = line.trim();
                this.addWord(line);

                // Nine Word test
                if (line.length() == 9) {
                    this.nineWordCount++;
                }
                this.totalWordCount++;
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.print(e);
        }
        this.isProcessed = true;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return True if valid words text file has been processed
     * Word file needs to be processed just once
     */
    public boolean isProcessed() {

        return this.isProcessed;
    }

    /**
     * Factory method to create Singleton Object
     * @return Singleton object
     */
    public static FastDictionary getInstance() {

        if (fastDictionary == null) {

            fastDictionary = new FastDictionary();
        }

        return fastDictionary;
    }

    public int getNineWordCount() {
        return this.nineWordCount;
    }
}

**Node**

package com.FastDictionary;

import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * Node of the Trie Data Structure used for FastDictionary
 */
public class DictionaryNode {

    // Character which the Node represents
    private char nodeChar;

    // Points to children
    private HashMap<Character, DictionaryNode> children = new HashMap<Character,DictionaryNode>();

    // Is Node the last character for a valid word
    private boolean isLeaf;

    /**
     * To create Root Node
     */
    DictionaryNode() {

        this.nodeChar = '.';
        this.isLeaf   = false;

    }

    /**
     * To create Child Node
     * @param c Character that Node represents
     */
    DictionaryNode(char c) {

        this.nodeChar = c;
        isLeaf        = false;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param c Character that Node represents
     * @return Child Node which was created
     */
    public DictionaryNode addChild(char c) {

        DictionaryNode child = new DictionaryNode(c);
        this.children.put(c, child);
        return child;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return true if Node is the last character for a valid word; default is false
     */
    public boolean isLeaf() {

        return this.isLeaf;
    }

    /**
     * Set Node as Leaf Node for a valid word
     */
    public void setLeaf() {

        this.isLeaf = true;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param c the character which the Child Node represnts
     * @return Child Node representing character c; null if no such Child exists
     */
    public DictionaryNode getChild(char c) {

        DictionaryNode child = this.children.get(c);

        return child;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far!

Comment: Till now, I have implemented the Trie for the dictionary and it works fine for searching. Should I add the code here or should I just explain how it is working? Apologies if I am not asking correctly. This is my first time on SO.

Comment: Definitely add the code here, adding code of what you have tried so far is very important on stack overflow!

Comment: I've added the code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, he only shows how to choose first character from root node. However, after you update your `currentNode` following that character, you can apply exact same principal to find next character from the new node. Another way of viewing what his algorithm did is, given a node, an integer L(5 in his example), finds i'th (1234 in his example) word which is in the subtree of that node and is exactly L depth away from it.

So after you have made your first move, you can recursively call that algorithm from new node, with `L-1` as depth. This is basic idea. Of course,some details need to be filled.

Firstly, updating `i` before next recursive call. Say algorithm chose first character to be `d`. And first 3 letters i.e `a b c` combinedly had `1000` 5-letter words. So now, you need to find `(1234-1000)=234th` word from this new node.

Secondly, instead of having `lengthFrequencyByLetter` and  `totalLengthFrequency` for entire tree,now you need to have them for every single node, which will require lots of ram. (you can optimize that by using HashMap though.)

A very high level implementation could be:

```
String randomWord(Node currentNode,int L,int index){
    if(L==0) return node.wordContainedWithin();
    char ch = find_next_character(node,L,index); //'d' in our example
    newNode = currentNode.getChild(ch); //node following d
    //following example, words_before = 1000
    int words_before = sum(lengthFrequencyByLetter[x][L] of all x before ch)
    int new_index = index - words_before;
    return randomWord(newNode,L-1,new_index);
}
```

Now to get a random L-letter word, look up root's `totalLengthFrequency[L]`, generate a number `i` (1234 here) between 0 to that value, and call `randomWord` as:

```
randomWord(tree.root,L,i)
```